# Do I need to re-set my wrist watch according to each country's timezone where i go during my travel?

Tags: air-travel, europe, planning

Do I need to re-set my wrist watch according to each country's timezone where i go during my travel? I'm mainly worrying about taking all the flights right time and reaching right time to airport. maybe it's not required , I just asked for confirmation.
 To give your answer you can take the example : I'm going to Amsterdam from India.

[image]

Comment: This is not really a constructive question.  You reset your watch for your convenience, so if it's just as convenient for you not to reset the watch and still tell local time then don't

Answer (score 2):

Itineraries are always stated in the local time.  Do whatever works for you.  Most people reset their watches when the enter a new time zone, but if you can do that conversion mentally, that's your own business.  If you're coming from a place in India that has an odd half-hour time zone, you should definitely reset your watch.

Answer (score 1):

I do if I'm in a different timezone for more than a day or so. Otherwise I just remember the time difference.

It's up to you really.